# Finding multinomial logit regression coefficients in R

Tags: regression, multinomial-distribution, logit

I run a multinomial logit regression model for a multiclass classification problem and use the following R function:

> trainedModel <- multinom(UNS ~ ., data = traindata)

Where `UNS` is the target variable. (There are 4 classes)

How can I find the the coefficients of the logit model trained for each class? When I print `trainedModel`, I get the coefficients for only three of the classes. One class goes missing. I am new to R and unable to understand what is happening here.

Can someone help me out with this?

Comment: What is the frequency of each level of UNS and how many predictors are there?  You will need at least $\max(96, 15p)$ in the least frequent level of the dependent variable in order to have a reliable model, where $p$ is the total number of parameters required to fit the predictors.  The 96 comes from the minimum sample size needed to estimate a proportion with a margin of error of $\pm 0.1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> One class goes missing. I am new to R and unable to understand what is happening here.

So this isn't an issue with R, one class should "go missing" in any software package you use.

The multinomial logit is estimated by regressing a log odds ratio against a set of linear predictors, and one of the classes is chosen as a pivot for the other variables.

For example, in the regular logit case, you have two classes, let's label them class `0` and class `1`. Let $Y_i$ be the class of observation $i$, and let $X_i$ be vector of predictors for observation $i$. Then a logistic regression estimates
$$\log\frac{\mathbb{P}(Y_i=1)}{\mathbb{P}(Y_i=0)} = \beta_0 X_i .$$
Here `0` is the pivot class. Note that there are two classes, but we only get one set of coefficients, namely $\beta_0$.

Now let's suppose we want to estimate a multinomial logit with three classes, and label the classes `0`, `1`, and `2`. Let's again choose `0` to be the pivot class. Then the multinomial logistic regression estimates the **two** equations
$$\log\frac{\mathbb{P}(Y_i=1)}{\mathbb{P}(Y_i=0)} = \beta_1 X_i$$
**and**
$$\log\frac{\mathbb{P}(Y_i=2)}{\mathbb{P}(Y_i=0)} = \beta_2 X_i .$$
Here, we have three classes, but two sets of coefficients, namely $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$.

Keep in mind that $\beta_0$, $\beta_1$, and $\beta_2$ are vectors, so if you have five predictors, then $\beta_1=(\beta_{1,1},\beta_{1,2},\beta_{1,3},\beta_{1,4},\beta_{1,5})^\prime$ and likewise for the other coefficient vectors.

Comment: @BlueMarker In the third equation, the numerator should read $\mathbb{P}(Y_i=2)$, right?

Answer (score 0):

In multinomial logit regression, for identification purpose, one set of coefficients associated with one choice (reference case) are set to zero. By restricting one set of coefficients to zero, there are n equations for n parameters. Hence, the system is identified. 
While interpreting the parameters, we interpret the odds of choice j relative to reference category. However, You can get the predicted probabilities and marginal effects for each choice by solving system of equations. You can look in Cameron and Trivedi (Multinomial Logit).